# How to convert this figure to .eps

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker, tikz-trees, eps, export

My code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%%
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newenvironment{multicases}[1]
{\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\left\lbrace\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\array{@{}l*{#1}{@{\quad}l}@{}}}
{\endarray\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\makeatother
%%


\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
{\footnotesize
\begin{forest}
/tikz/every node/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
for tree={
if level=0{align=center}{
    align={@{}P{23mm}@{}}
                            },
grow=east,
draw,
font=\footnotesize,
edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(3mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
parent anchor=east,
child anchor=west,
l sep=10mm,
tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
fill=white,
rounded corners=2pt,
drop shadow,
        }
[root
[2, edge+={-stealth}
    [22, edge+={-stealth}
        [223, edge+={-stealth}]
        [222, edge+={-stealth}]
        [221, edge+={-stealth}
            [2211, edge+={-stealth}]
        ]
    ]
    [21, edge+={-stealth}]
]
[1, edge+={-stealth}
    [11, edge+={-stealth}
        [113, edge+={-stealth}]
        [112, edge+={-stealth}]
        [111, edge+={-stealth}]
    ]
]
]
\end{forest}
}
\caption{My Figure}
\label{Fig}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

I want to export and save this figure in .eps format.

I am using overleaf and TexMaker software.

How to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: use latex then dvips -E

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, how to do that please ?

Comment: if your file is xxx.tex type `latex xxx` then `dvips -E xxx` and you will have an EPS file (why do you want EPS, it's something of a legacy format these days)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. Actually, this is for a journal submission. My .tex won't be convert to pdf in the scholarOne platform because of that. Kindly, where should I write this command within the TexMaker software ? thank you again

Comment: no idea about texmaker just type it on the commandline

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the "How to do that"-question hints at the fact that not everyone using LaTeX is also used to or familiar with working with command lines. Especially Windows users quite often have a hard time with it, because it is not a way of doing things in that ecosytem.

Comment: this may help (change PNG to EPS) https://latexdraw.com/how-to-convert-a-latex-pdf-to-png/

Comment: @BlackMild going via png would mean the eps is just a bitmap, ther should be no need to do that it could be a scalable image using fonts and drawn lines

Comment: If you have `Acrobat Professional`, then there is an option available to save as `EPS` format...For this you have to create PDF from your code and then proceed...

Comment: I believe Inkscape, an open-source software, can open PDF files, automatically convert them to editable SVG files, which you can then "Save as" EPS. :D

Answer (score 4):

I just tried an online converter at https://cloudconvert.com/pdf-to-eps. Your pdf file was successfully converted to an eps file:

[image]